# Get checkbox values in javascript

Tags: javascript

Roughly, this is my code:

```
<form name="mpform" id="mpform">
<input type="checkbox" onclick="mpfunc()" id="mpay" name="mpay[]" value="19" style="float:left;" />
//many of the above input tag - only the value changes with other numbers
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function mpfunc()
{
var comp=0;
document.getElementById("mpaydiv").style.visibility="visible";
for(var i=0; i< document.getElementById("mpform").elements['mpay[]'].length;i++){
if(document.getElementById("mpform").elements['mpay[]'][i].checked)
comp = comp + document.getElementById("mpform").elements['mpay[]'][i].value;
}
document.getElementById("mpaydiv").innerHTML=comp;
}
</script>
<div id="mpaydiv" style="position:fixed; right:0; visibility:hidden; bottom:0; border:1px solid black; background-color:white; padding:2px 2px;"></div></div>
    </div>

    <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

I have tried substituting getElementById("mpform") with form[0],mpform and others but I cant seem to access the values. With the current getelementid I get

> Error: document.getElementById("mpform") is null Source File:
>   index.php?page=fakturi Line: 3938

With mpform I get mpform is undefined as with form[0]
Please help. How do I get the sum of the values of all selected checkboxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to recall IE having issues with the 0 index of the forms array. You can access it through, `document.getElementsByName("mpform")[0]` or `document.forms['mpform']`. To get the checkbox descendants, you might use `getElementById('mpay')` or `document.getElementsByName("mpay")[0]` or `document.getElementsByName("mpform")[0].elements[0]`

Comment: Error: document.forms.mpform is undefined
Source File: index.php?page=fakturi
Line: 3938

Error: document.getElementsByName("mpform")[0] is undefined
Source File: index.php?page=fakturi
Line: 3938

I tried it even though I'm using FireFox

Comment: Are you sure that the form is actually there? What do you see when you do CTRL + U?

Comment: Thank you for making me look at my code. I had a previous form tag that wasn't closed.

Answer (score 2):

The id of your form must be mpform.  You have name="mpform".  Add id="mpform".

Also, for efficiency sake, you should change your function to this.  Using multiple getElementById for grabbing the same element is very inefficient.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function mpfunc()
{
   var comp=0;
   document.getElementById("mpaydiv").style.visibility="visible";
   var elements = document.getElementById("mpform").elements;
   for(var i=0; i< elements.length;i++){
      if(elements[i].type == 'checkbox' && elements[i].checked)
         comp = comp + parseInt(elements[i].value);
   }
   document.getElementById("mpaydiv").innerHTML=comp;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, sorry I changed it. Same result though:
Error: document.getElementById("mpform") is null
Source File: index.php?page=fakturi
Line: 3938

Comment: With the change of the function I get this: Error: document.getElementById("mpform") is null
Source File: index.php?page=fakturi
Line: 3938

Comment: I just edited my script.  I believe the problem was the way you were accessing the elements.  I just tested the script I just posted with your html code and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

Should be like this

```
     <form name="mpform" id="mpform"></form>
```

Comment: Yes, sorry I changed it. Same result though:
Error: document.getElementById("mpform") is null
Source File: index.php?page=fakturi
Line: 3938

Answer (score 1):

You try to get Element By **Id** but you specified a name for it.

```
<form id="mpform">
```

Comment: Yes, sorry I changed it. Same result though:
Error: document.getElementById("mpform") is null
Source File: index.php?page=fakturi
Line: 3938

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that the function is running before the form element has finished loading? Try running the function as part of the `window.onload` event.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this out using your html code, and it seems to work.  I edited my answer above to show this, but also posted it as another answer to make sure you saw.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function mpfunc()
{
   var comp=0;
   document.getElementById("mpaydiv").style.visibility="visible";
   var elements = document.getElementById("mpform").elements;
   for(var i=0; i< elements.length;i++){
      if(elements[i].type == 'checkbox' && elements[i].checked)
         comp = comp + parseInt(elements[i].value);
   }
   document.getElementById("mpaydiv").innerHTML=comp;
}
</script>
```